# XAMPP with MySQL instead of MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, mariadb

I'm trying to learn PHP + MySQL from a book and I want to change MariaDB with MySQL.

So far I tried using an older version of xampp (nov 2015) but it still got MariaDB and using this:
https://gist.github.com/odan/c799417460470c3776ffa8adce57eece

Unfortunately, it did not work:

```
9:48:04 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
9:48:04 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
9:48:04 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
9:48:04 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:48:04 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:48:04 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:48:04 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
9:48:04 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

Should I try to get a XAMPP version with MySQL instead of MariaDB (and that would be a really old version? if so, can you give me one?)

How can I fix it?
I got nothing in Event Viewer nor in the error log. (tbh I think xampp is displaying me another log, because the last line is from 21:11 PM and it does not update).

Ideas on replacing MariaDB with MySQL, keeping in mind the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not exactly what you want but I have to ask: Why would you like to replace MariaDB with MySQL?
They are **very similar** (see [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/120224)) and it would probably be more of a hassle to replace the MariaDB Server in XAMPP with something else that to just stick with MariaDB.

I think that is perfectly **fine to use MariaDB instead of MySQL** in most, if not all cases. They claim that MariaDB has speed improvements, but the queries should be the same, as stated in the linked post above. I have been using XAMPP for quite some time for local testing and have never yet encountered a problem between the two.